# React js : Uncaught TypeError: props.onEnterTask is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**//Newtask.js**

```
   import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import useHttp from "../hookes/useHttp";
import Taskform from "./taskform";
const newTask = (props) => {
  const createTask = (tastk, taskdata) => {
    const data = { id: taskdata.name, text: tastk };
    props.onAddTask(data);
  };

  const { isloading, error, sendRequest: fetchRequest } = useHttp();

  const enterTaskHandler = async (tasktext) => {
    fetchRequest(
      {
        url: "https://react-prep-d4d1d-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/comments.json",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: { text: tasktext },
      },
      createTask.bind(null, tasktext)
    );
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <Taskform onEnterTask={enterTaskHandler} loading={isloading} />
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
    </section>
  );
};
export default newTask;
```

Here above i am calling TaskForm compoenet and passing arguments ( props)

**//taskform.js**

```
  import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./taskforms.css";
function Taskform(props) {
  const [text, settext] = useState();
  const Inputchangehandler = (event) => {
    settext(event.target.value);
  };
  console.log(props.onEnterTask);
  const submithandler = (text) => {
    props.onEnterTask(text);
    settext("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={Inputchangehandler}
        className="asit"
      />
      <button className="asit" onClick={submithandler}></button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Taskform;
```

//Here in taskform i am calling the props.onEnterTask(text)....but i am getting error

**Error : Uncaught TypeError: props.onEnterTask is not a function**

**//useHttp.js ( hook)**

```
 import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

const useHttp = () => {
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const sendRequest = useCallback(async (requestConfig, applydata) => {
    setisLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(requestConfig.url, {
        method: requestConfig.method ? requestConfig.method : "GET",
        headers: requestConfig.headers ? requestConfig.headers : {},
        body: requestConfig.body ? JSON.stringify(requestConfig.body) : null,
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Request failed!");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      applydata(data);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message || "Something went wrong!");
    }
    setisLoading(false);
  }, []);
  return {
    isLoading,
    error,
    sendRequest,
  };
};

export default useHttp;
```

Please kindly go through this above files and let me know the issue.

Comment: what is the value passed in "enterTaskHandler" ?

Comment: The error means exactly what it says, the value that you are passing as `onEnterTask` is not a function. Could you share your code for `enterTaskHandler`?

Comment: could share the code of those two files please ?

Comment: Please kindly go through again ,  i have inputed all component code , in edit

Comment: Try to "console.log" the props in Taskform component, to verify which props you get. Maybe you another place where this component is used, and props are not passed into it.

Comment: I am getting "{}" when i console.log(props), and  getting undefine when i do console.log(props.onEnterTask)

Comment: how do you export Taskform component, and where is "submithandler" called?

Comment: submithandler is when the form is submited , and export default Taskform;

Comment: Check i have added taskform compoent ...

Comment: small typo: it should be `onClick={() => submithandler(text)}`

Comment: did you define fetchRequest somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the issue is not with props , some other component issue was there in app file , i was giving some other componet as start file //////

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).